# Unable to use Docker Compose 3.5 features

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup some docker-compose scripts using some of the latest compose 3.5 features. The big one is being able to name networks. So there are some containers that I end up reproducing over and over again, such as a Postgres database, with various apps I work on. My goal is to be able to have a docker-compose script for something like Postgres, with a named network, which I can then have other apps with their own docker-compose scripts just add on to. It feels more re-usable that way.

Anyway, here is the docker-compose script I'm working with:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: postgres
    networks:
      - pg_network
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ~/.postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ~/.postgresql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    networks:
      - pg_network
    ports:
      - 5433:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - ~/.postgresql/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin

networks:
  pg_network:
    name: pg_network
```

I am trying to use the "custom name" feature new in Docker Compose 3.5. See this link for the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

However, when I try to run `docker-compose up -d`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
networks.pg_network value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, I'm running the Docker commands with `sudo` (because that seems to be a requirement on Ubuntu).

Here are my Docker and Docker Compose versions:

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
```

I've tried upgrading them with APT, but it says they are up to date.

So, either I'm making a mistake in my compose script, or there's something screwy with my Docker version.

Comment: [Docker Compose 1.17.1](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/1.17.1) only supports Compose file format 3.4.

Comment: So how do I upgrade compose?

Comment: An easy way in your case is to install it with pip instead of apt to get a more recent version `apt remove docker-compose && pip install docker-compose`. [See all the other possibilities](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)